# For the ajax url shows 404 on the AWS tomcat log

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, amazon-web-services

I was using ***MVN install*** deploy my code on the AWS tomcat. I did this by directly open the *AWSname*:8080/manager/html and upload the WAR file(I am not sure if it is the correct way). The server can load the index.html successfully as my expectation and shows page on the front-end, but error went to call AJAX, which is in Javascript file, it always return 404. The servlet's url pattern will be like this

[AJAX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY0AH.png)

[Login Servlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOH48.png)

I **tested everything fine** on my localhost:8080, but in the AWS tomcat, the log showed like this.

[Tomcat Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGvLk.png)

I've never met such a case before, could somebody give me some useful suggestions on the possible solutions?

Comment: Please post the code here rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

from your description it is not clear if you have multiple apps/war/containers/servers.

From your message you have a UI, which seems not to be bundled into your war file. To check in this case use these steps to check your setups

1. Add a index.html to your root in the war file and test if you can access it locally.
2. if this works, deploy on AWS and try to access the same path on AWS.
3. if the page is showing, your context is defined well on AWS. So you have an issue with your URL mappings
4. But if it does not show, you have a URL problem (wrong URL on AWS)